# Não faz insert em banco Oracle, com NHibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-insert, nhibernate

Estou com um problema em uma aplicação, desenvolvida em C#, que utiliza banco de dados Oracle, e acessa o banco com NHibernate.

Ao tentar realizar a função SaveOrUpdate(), não é feito o insert e não gera nenhum erro.
Ao realizar o Debug (via Visual Studio), nenhuma exceção ou erro é gerado.

Fazendo o insert "na mão", direto pelo SQL Developer, funciona normalmente. Somente na aplicação que não realiza a inserção.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue parte do código que é feito o insert.

```
public SenhaAtendimento GeraSenhaAtendimento(int unidadeId, TipoSenha tipoSenha)
    {
        var seq = 1;

        var maxIdCrit = DetachedCriteria.For<SenhaAtendimento>()
            .CreateAlias("Unidade", "u")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.Id", unidadeId))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Tipo", tipoSenha))
            .SetProjection(Projections.Max("Id"));

        var lista = Session.CreateCriteria<SenhaAtendimento>()
            .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("Id", maxIdCrit))
            .List<SenhaAtendimento>();

        if (lista.Any())
        {
            seq = lista.First().Sequencia + 1;
        }

        var sa = new SenhaAtendimento()
        {
            DataAbertura = Now.Date,
            Tipo = tipoSenha,
            Unidade = new Unidade() {Id = unidadeId},
            Sequencia = seq
        };

            Session.SaveOrUpdate(sa);

        return sa;
    }
```

Comment: Consegui encontrar o problema. Era preciso abrir uma transaction e realizar o commit, já que a função SaveOrUpdate() não faz autocommit.